# APEX: Assigning a Campaign Id to Campaign Members Issue

Tags: apex, campaign, clone, campaign-member

I am trying to reassign the  `campaignid` of some existing `campaign members` by creating a clone of them and inserting them afterwards.

Firstly I have the following 2 observations:

- the hardcoded `campaignid` is valid and is the id of an existing campaign
- the size of `cmember` is >0

  ```
  List<CampaignMember> campaignmembers = new List<CampaignMember>();

    for(CampaignMember c : cmember)
   {   
      CampaignMember campMemb = c.clone(false, true);
      campMemb.Campaignid='70.......DE';


     campaignmembers.add(campMemb);
   }
  ```

  insert campaignmembers;

Upon running this script I get the following error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Attempted to add a campaign member where either the member id 'null' or the campaign id '70.....ZGDE' is null.: []

Comment: Try hard coding a LeadId or ContactId on the CampaignMember record.  If that works it would point to the Clone method not bringing over the Ids as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be caused by the fact that some records from `cmember` had either the lead or the contact id, hence I had to add the following statement which solved my problem.

```
List<CampaignMember> campaignmembers = new List<CampaignMember>();

  for(CampaignMember c : cmember)
 {   
   if(c.leadid!=null)
   {
    CampaignMember cm= New CampaignMember (leadid=c.leadid, campaignid=c.campaignid...etc);
    campaignmembers.add(cm);
    }

 if(c.contactid!=null)
 {
  CampaignMember cm= New CampaignMember (contactid=c.contactid, campaignid=c.campaignid...etc);
   campaignmembers.add(cm);
 }


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

While creating the CampaignMember use like this:

```
CampaignMember cm= New CampaignMember(CampaignId=UTMCampaign.Id, ContactId= con.Id, Status='Opt-In');
```

here `contactid` or `leadid` is mandatory:
see some more details about the campaignmember fields:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm